# "Nice little place you've got here" - is it derogatory?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

That is, does "little place" imply that the place is small, but pretty nevertheless? When told, would this offend a person owning a large mansion?

Comment: Ask yourself why anyone would use this expression when talking to someone who lives in a mansion (or palace). It's got to be at least *jocular*, so the only real question is whether the speaker is laughing *with* or *at* the comfortably-housed person.

Comment: I think the situation where it could be offensive is if the speaker is even better off and they both know it.

Comment: I can see 1001 situations where it would be offensive, and another 1001 situations where it would not be offensive. The specifics of the context will determine the intent of the content.

Comment: When did ELU become a site for human-relationship advice?

Comment: I think the more accurate descriptive term for the phrase, when the comment is not intended in a genuinely admiring way, is _patronizing_, thanks to the diminishing effect of "little" on what would otherwise unmistakably be a compliment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be appropriate in basically two situations:

1. The "place" really is little, "you", either explicitly or by implication, acknowledges this, and there's no sense pretending that it isn't.  In that case the sentence is just saying that the place is nice, and phrased with "little" implies that it's pleasantly "cozy".
2. The "place" is unusually large.  In this case the sentence is acknowledging the size (via irony) and is implying that you're impressed with it.

You would probably NOT want to use the sentence if the "place" is of average size or maybe a hair larger, and is clearly not exceptional in some way.

But a lot depends on the dynamics between the speaker and the person who is "you".  Generally you should not use the sentence in a formal setting or if you have not established at least a passing friendship with the person.

Answer (score 1):

> When told, would this offend a person owning a large mansion?

Not necessarily, but people can take offence at all sort of things.

What this really highlights though, is the use of:

> Irony

Comment: I'd call a large mansion a 'nice little joint', so as to show the proper respect. Crib or crashpad might also be used.